# How can I get the first selection of a layer in a QgsMapLayerComboBox?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, combo-box

I'm developing a very simple QGIS plugin to calculate raster average by using **GDAL**. It uses a **QgsMapLayerComboBox** and a filter to select only raster layers. However, it needs to select twice a layer at the Combo Box to produce the expected results. The snipped code is:

```
.
.
.
def initGui(self):
        """Create the menu entries and toolbar icons inside the QGIS GUI."""

        icon_path = ':/plugins/AverageRaster/AverageRaster.png'
        self.add_action(
            icon_path,
            text=self.tr(u'To calculate raster average'),
            callback=self.run,
            parent=self.iface.mainWindow())

        self.wcb = QgsMapLayerComboBox(self.dlg)
        self.wcb.setFixedWidth(220)
        self.wcb.move(140,40)
        self.wcb.setFilters( QgsMapLayerProxyModel.RasterLayer )
.
.
.

def run(self):
    """Run method that performs all the real work"""
    #My code starts here
    layer = self.wcb.currentLayer()
.
.
.
    self.dlg.show()
    # Run the dialog event loop
    result = self.dlg.exec_()
    # See if OK was pressed
    if result:
        # Do something useful here - delete the line containing pass and
        # substitute with your code.
        #My code starts here
        message = "the raster average of " + filename + " is = " + str(average) 
        QMessageBox.information(None, "Raster Average", message)
        #My code ends here
```

At the next image, my Plugin is determining the average of **ndvi.tif** raster. If I want the average of **utah_demUTM2.tif**, the expected value is obtained only at the second chance. How can I get the average at the first selection of a layer at the **QgsMapLayerComboBox**.

[image]

---

Afterward that I tried out a lot of possibilities, I found a possible solution but, I don't like it very much because I have to click on icon plugin again and not on a OK button.

At the 'Property Editor' of Qt Designer, I unmarked the 'OK' button and I modified the label "Click on OK to get raster average" for this one: "Click on plugin icon again to get raster average".

After reloaded the plugin, I observed that the order in the Combo Box was alphabetic.

[image]

When I selected anyone of these layers (see above image) and I clicked on icon plugin, its behavior was always as expected and the principal Dialog never closed.

[image]

---

I changed the **QMessageBox** for a **QTextBrowser** and put again the OK button at the widget Dialog. In this case, I could observe that the **QgsMapLayerComboBox** has the expected behavior when I select the raster layer. The problem is when I clicked on the OK buttom. The Dialog was closed and I need to launch the plugin again to see the results. It is possible to keep the window Dialog open when the OK button is clicked?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution:

```
.
.
.

    def __init__(self, iface):
.
.
.
        okButton = self.dlg.pushButton
        okButton.connect(okButton, SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.myFunction)
.
.
.
    def myFunction(self):
    """Run method that performs all the real work"""
.
.
.
    def run(self):
.
.
.
```

It was necessary to create a new **Ok** button and the old **OK** button, from **button_box**, it was hidden.

Comment: Hint: you should use [new-style-signal](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html) instead. `okButton.clicked.connect(self.myFunction)`

Answer (score 3):

I tried this and it worked :

in your function **run** :

Put the line ***layer = self.wcb.currentLayer()***

after ***if result:***

It did what I think you wanted it to do.

On a side note : you know you can make your app calculate the average without clicking on ok? If you play with the signals, you can make a text appear in your main window each time you change selection.

Comment: I had implemented this before your answer. Thanks, but it doesn't work. +1 for your "On a side note". I have to explore this possibility.